# Binding issue WPF

Tags: wpf, telerik, telerik-charting

I am new at WPF and of course I faced some issues with Bindings.

I have initialized RadCartesianChart and I want display data from different type of category lists. For each of those lists I want different color, but I fail to Bind Fill property to my Color property in code behind.

This is how my XAML looks like:

```
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart Name="RevChart">
        <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
            <telerik:CartesianChartGrid MajorYLineDashArray="5, 5" MajorLinesVisibility="Y">
                <telerik:CartesianChartGrid.MajorYLineStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Line}">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Gray"/>
                    </Style>
                </telerik:CartesianChartGrid.MajorYLineStyle>
            </telerik:CartesianChartGrid>
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
        <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
            <telerik:CategoricalAxis />
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
        <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
            <telerik:LinearAxis/>
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>

        <telerik:AreaSeries CategoryBinding="Date" ValueBinding="Rev" Fill="{Binding Color}">

        </telerik:AreaSeries>

    </telerik:RadCartesianChart>
```

This is my C# code:

```
public class Revenue
{
    public double Rev { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

List<Revenue> list = new List<Revenue>();
...
...
this.RevChart.Series[0].ItemsSource = list;
```

As a results I am getting correct picture, but color is default. So my binding of Color doesn't work. Is it problem in this line `Fill={Binding Color}` ? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Its because `Fill` is a `Brush` and you are trying to assign a `Color`, this wont work.

You will have to assign your `Color` to the `Color` property of a `SolidColorBrush` in the `Fill` property.

Example

```
<telerik:AreaSeries CategoryBinding="Date" ValueBinding="Rev">
    <telerik:AreaSeries.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}" />
    </telerik:AreaSeries.Fill>
</telerik:AreaSeries>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Completely make sense but unfortunately as soon as I add `<telerik:AreaSeries.Fill> .... </>` It won't display anything at all just empty chart.

Comment: I guess you will have to check the `telerik` documentaion and see if they allow this, seems strange that they would not, otherwise you will have to make a `Converter` or make `Color` a `Brush`